# Limit calculation formalization

Tags: limits

I am supposed to calculate$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{7x-\cos x}{2x+\sin x}$

I think the limit should be 3.5 because the $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ terms are bounded, so we are left with ${7x \over 2x}$ which approaches $\frac{7}{2}$ at infinity.

This sounds really unformal, and maybe even incorrect. I tried applying L'Hopital but it didn't help much.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You only need that

$$\begin{cases}\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0\\{}\\g(x)\;\;\text{bounded in some neighborhood of}\;\;x_0\end{cases}\;\;\implies \lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)g(x)=0$$

and the above includes, mutatis mutandis, the case $\;x_0=\infty\;$ , so now you can use simply arithmetic of limits:

$$\frac{7x-\cos x}{2x+\sin x}=\frac{7-\frac{\cos x}x}{2+\frac{\sin x}x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\frac{7-0}{2+0}=\frac72$$

Comment: Great, I also learnt a new latin phrase. Thanks!

Comment: @Whyka Good for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite your quotient in the form $$\frac{7-\frac{\cos(x)}{x}}{2+\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$$

Comment: I tried that, but the limit is at $\infty$, not 0, so I left it.

Comment: Oh, now I see it was a good idea. Thanks!